# How to create array of functions dynamically?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

What if i want to have an array of pointers to a function and the size of the array is not known from the beginning? I'm just curious if there's a way to do that. Using new statement or maybe something else. Something looking similar to

```
void (* testArray[5])(void *) = new void ()(void *);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

typedef void (*FunPointer)(void *);
std::vector<FunPointer> pointers;
```

If you really want to use a static array, it would be better to do it using the `FunPointer` i defined in the snippet above:

```
FunPointer testArray[5];
testArray[0] = some_fun_pointer;
```

Though i would still go for the vector solution, taking into account that you don't know the size of the array during compilation time and that you are using C++ and not C.

Answer (score 5):

With `typedef`, the new expression is trivial:

```
typedef void(*F)(void*);

int main () {
  F *testArray = new F[5];
  if(testArray[0]) testArray[0](0);
}
```

Without `typedef`, it is somewhat more difficult:

```
void x(void*) {}
int main () {
  void (*(*testArray))(void*) = new (void(*[5])(void*));
  testArray[3] = x;

  if(testArray[3]) testArray[3](0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
A[i]=new node
```

or

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<someObj*> x;
x.resize(someSize);
```